# mvc - ajax pager - make current page inactive link

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is my ajax pager code below:  Now I want to make sure that the link for the current page is unclickable and css should reflect that as well.  My pager is keeping track of the current page number, so that is not a problem. The concern is how should I go about making that particular link unclickable and look different (without writing a bunch of crazy if-else blocks)?

```
 <%if(Model.num_pages > 1){ %>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><%=Model.Total%></td>
    <td><%=Ajax.ActionLink("1",
                Model.originalAction, 
                Model.originalController, 
                new { Page = 1, totalNumber = Model.Total, comments = (object)null, divToUpdate = Model.divToUpdate, videoId  = Model.carrierId },
                        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.divToUpdate, OnBegin = "commentBegin", OnComplete = "commentEnd" })%></td>
    <%if (Model.num_pages > 3)
      { %>   
      <td>         
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                Model.originalAction,
                Model.originalController,
                new {totalNumber = Model.Total, comments = (object)null, divToUpdate = Model.divToUpdate, videoId = Model.carrierId },
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.divToUpdate, OnBegin = "commentBegin", OnComplete = "commentEnd" }))
      {%>
    <%=Html.DropDownList("Page", Model.dropDown)%>
    <input value = "jump" type = "submit" />
      <%} %>
      </td>
      <%} %>
      <%else
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < Model.num_pages; i++)
            {%>
           <td>
           <%=Ajax.ActionLink(i.ToString(),
                    Model.originalAction,
                    Model.originalController,
                        new { Page = i, totalNumber = Model.Total, comments = (object)null, divToUpdate = Model.divToUpdate, videoId = Model.carrierId},
                           new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.divToUpdate, OnBegin = "commentBegin", OnComplete = "commentEnd" })%>
          </td>
        <% }
        }%>

    <td><%=Ajax.ActionLink(Model.num_pages.ToString(), 
                  Model.originalAction,
                    Model.originalController,
                new { Page = Model.num_pages, totalNumber = Model.Total, comments = (object)null, divToUpdate = Model.divToUpdate, videoId = Model.carrierId},
                        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.divToUpdate, OnBegin = "commentBegin", OnComplete = "commentEnd" })%></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <%} %>
```

Comment: I don't think 1 more if else is going to matter, frankly

Comment: you think I'm using too many if-else? and it's not going to be just 1 more if-else... it's going to be a few of them.  If you know how to accomplish this using only one more if, then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

progtick - i think you'd be better off creating an htmlhelper for this. I've done this in the past with great success. basically, it's a one liner:

```
/* the 1st param is your target div
   the 2nd parameter true/false merely indicates whether
   the helper should run in querystring postback or ajax mode
*/
<%=Html.Pagination("TargetDiv", true) %>
```

and here's how it looks (with unreserved apologies to SO for the obvious influence!!):

[image]

**[update]** you can grab a working example of this from here:

http://www.gatehousemusic.com/downloads/MvcApplication2.1.zip

let me know how you get on.

Comment: yeah I don't know how to tweak this to fit my Ajax.ActionLink approach, but let's see..

Comment: I was going to get rid of my ActionLink approach and your pager instead, but I noticed two things that you may know how to deal with: 1)I don't like appending "#" in URL 2)it doesn't degrade when you disable javascript

Comment: hi progtick, i've updated my sample. you can use 'javascript:void(0);' in place of #. the new example has this.. as far as degrading javascript is concerned, it was just a matter of running an each function over the href links on page load. i've done this too. see new sample!! (basically, the default is to have normal querystring params on the href. then replace these with javascript:void(0) in jquery if javascript is enabled). note, the link has changed to: http://www.gatehousemusic.com/downloads/MvcApplication2.1.zip

Comment: glad to have been of assistance :) - htmlhelpers, especially when used with interfaces and generated jquery/javascript are pretty awesome. let me know if you make any improvements on the code..