# Paging with ASP.NET MVC (URL manipulation?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Hi,**

I am building a HTML helper in ASP.NET MVC to handle the paging of a forum/threads. A object will be passed from the modelView to the HTML helper that holds the followin information :

CurrentPageNr
ObjectsPerPage
TotalAmountOfObjects

My thought is to generate a html output that will render somthing like this :

[FirstPage] [PrivousePage] [1] [2] [3] [4] [**5**] [6] [7] [8] [9] [NextPage] [LastPage]

The question is how to handle the click. The solutions I have found so far is the following :

**Solution 1:** Let each link be a button that sets a hidden field(currentPage) and then submits the form

**Solution 2:** I could manipulate the current url(absolutURI) and set it as links in the page. The problem here will be that the href could be vary long(for each link). The other problem is that I havent found a easy way to manipulate the querystring so if I have to do this manually it would be som work :

Replace : "&ASP_P=[currentPage]" Or
Replace : "ASP_P=[currentPage]" if there is a ? before the ASP_P

**Pleas Advice**

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make another variable NumberOfPages which is (Total Size / ObjectsPerPage) rounded up.

Then simply loop through each "page" and generate the href for the links:

A crude example follows:

```
public static string GetPageNumberLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string nameOfPageParameter, int pageNumber)
{
       //set the placeholder
       string queryValues = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query;
       helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values[nameOfPageParameter] = "..PAGEHERE..";
       string virtualPath = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Route.GetVirtualPath(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values).VirtualPath;

       return helper.ResolveUrl("~/" + virtualPath.Replace("..PAGEHERE..", pageNumber.ToString())) + queryValues;
}
```

Comment: @The_Butcher > This seems to be what I am searching for. If I got it right I will not have to manually replace the parameter and its value? this looks to be somthing like Request.QueryString? I will try it out as soon as I can.

Comment: yeah you just have to supply the name of the parameter. Its flexible so you can use it with any name

Comment: @The_Butcher > I have now tried this but there is som questions : My Query will look like this : ?F.ShowF=0&ALS.CP=20&ALS.ST=0&ALS.P=2, the ALS.P is the current PageNr. When running RouteData.Values["ALS.P"] I will get null? Do I need to add some special routs for this? Also the VirtualPath will only contain "Ad/List" (Controller/Action) nothing more? So there will not be any page to replace? Then you add queryValues at the end that will start with "?", is this really right?

Comment: Hey SnowJim, yes this solution requires that the page variable is in the route value collection. i.e You have setup a custom route that can map to a "page" variable

Comment: @The_Butcher > Do you got an example on how this route could look like?

Comment: add the route to your Global.asax file before the default mvc one:

routes.MapRoute(
                "Paging", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{F.ShowF}/{ALS.CP}/{ALS.ST}/{ALS.P}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", F.ShowF = "",ALS.CP="",ALS.ST="", ALS.P = 1 } // Parameter defaults
            );

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  public Index(int? page)
        {

int pageSize=10;    
var List= Repo.GetAllMembers();    
var paginatedList = List.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
return View(paginatedList);    
}
```

give pageSize as number of records you want to dispaly

Then Register a new  mapping Rule using  MapRoute() helper method in Global.asax

Comment: im not sure what this method will do? I was first implemented a paginatedList but then i moved this out to a special object that holds all settings of the list(pages, itemsPerPage, ListMode, and so on).

Comment: SnowJim, this link may be helpfulpl [link](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm)

Comment: > Yes this was my first attempt but it is not handling already existing url(querystring values) and its really this that is the hard part. I replaced the IPagedList with a another ListSettings class that fits my site better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Conery wrote an HTML Helper class for this for MVC.  You can find the details [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/10/aspnet-mvc-pagedlistt/) .   I'm actually using it successfully on my [site](http://www.alwaysmoveforward.com/software/Blog/Index) if you want to see it in action.  Just scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: > Yes this was my first attempt but it is not handling already existing url(querystring values) and its really this that is the hard part. I replaced the IPagedList with a another ListSettings class that fits my site better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: yeah you have to take existing querystring parameters and pass them into an object array as the last parameter of the HTML.Pager class.  That step is less than ideal.  Glad you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

SnowJim,

I created a little example of this using thr IpgaedList interface as per rob connerys. I actually pointed another SO user at it a while  baclk. You can find the replay here:

[mvc - ajax pager - make current page inactive link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148219/mvc-ajax-pager-make-current-page-inactive-link)

along with links to the download for the full example.

Comment: > Yes this was my first attempt but it is not handling already existing url(querystring values) and its really this that is the hard part. I replaced the IPagedList with a another ListSettings class that fits my site better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: oh well, at least you've gone down the road of 'discounting' approaches. good luck in the search